# Deserializing JSON with Nullable DateTime property throws Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException

Tags: .net-core, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize following JSON string below

```
[
  {
    "gerceklesenTarih": 1487710800000,
    "deletedDate": null
  }
]
```

to Dto object below (I simplified the class for clarification).

```
public class Dto
{
   public DateTime? gerceklesenTarih { get; set; }
   public DateTime? deletedDate { get; set; }
}
```

with code :

```
if(File.Exists("aa - Copy.txt"))
{
     var OdemePlaniStr = File.ReadAllText("aa - Copy.txt");
     var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
     {                    
         Converters = { new DateTimeConverter() },
     };
     var resultOdemePlani = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dto>>(OdemePlaniStr, settings);
}
```

As the JSON object I consume sends datetime values as long, I have to use a Converter class below

```
    public class DateTimeConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(DateTime);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            try
            {
                var t = (long)reader.Value;
                //return DateTime.Parse(t.ToString());
                return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddMilliseconds(t);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            writer.WriteValue(Convert.ToInt64(((DateTime)value - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalMilliseconds));
        }
    }
```

Deserializing non nullable DateTime fields have no problem, however when JSON object has a value in its nullable DateTime field, it throws :

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: 1. Path '[0].gerceklesenTarih', line 4, position 25.'
```

When I debug the code, it doesn't hit DateTimeConverter class even if it should. Additionally below notation works

```
"gerceklesenTarih": "/Date(1487710800000)/"
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it, forgot to add nullable type to CanConvert method of DateTimeConverter

```
public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
{
    return objectType == typeof(DateTime);
}
```

It works as expected now